# Return object instead of an Array of one object in Sequelize

Tags: angular, express, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

*Been looking for similar questions without success.* I currently have an Angular app and a NodeJS/Express server and using Sequelize for MariaDB.

I have a table I want to collect stats from and return as an simple object.

```
getPlayerStats = function(callback) {
  Player.findAll({
    attributes: [
      [sequelize.fn('sum', sequelize.col('points')), 'totalPointsEarned'],
      [sequelize.fn('count', sequelize.col('id')), 'totalPlayers'],
      [sequelize.fn('sum', sequelize.col('online')), 'totalOnline']
    ]
  }).then(playerStats => callback(playerStats));
};
```

'

```
  app.get("/info/player-stats", function(request, response) {
    sql.getPlayerStats(result => response.send(result));
  });
```

This gives me the following output:

```
[
    {
        "totalPointsEarned": 457,
        "totalPlayers": 5,
        "totalOnline": 2
    }
]
```

This is causing issues when displaying the data in DOM, if I handle it as an object Angular won't display anything. If I handle it as an array with `*ngFor='let player of players'` it will display the data in DOM but gives me an error exception:

`ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays`

**If** I receive the following output: {}

```
{
    "totalPointsEarned": 457,
    "totalPlayers": 5,
    "totalOnline": 2
}
```

.. instead of [{}] I believe it will be easier for me to display the data in DOM.

I believe I will be in need to change something about the first batch of code posted here (Sequelize part) to get a single object in return instead of an array with only one object. Any advice or suggestions are more than welcome.

Thanks in advance,
Svante

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your needs.
`findAll` returns an array because you want to find all cases matches the query (so it might be some objects in an array).
If your query always returns a single object you can use `find` instead of `findAll` and then you'll get an object.

Otherwise, just use `[].map()` or `[].forEach` functions at your backend in order to access any object inside the array.

Comment: Thank you for your engagement, replacing `findAll` with `findOne` and it returned it as an object instead of an array.